# How to save search, choose a recent search and then populate the form using jQuery and/or asp.net like priceline does

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, json, forms

I want to do something similar to what priceline does. It saves the recent searches in a dropdown menu. When you pick one from the recent search. The form will be populated accordingly.

This is what I am thinking. (1) Save the searches into an array in a cookie (2), when a recent search item is chosen, retrive the corresponding array element from the cookie and then populate the form. What do you think is the best way to implement this? I especially want to know how to save the form entries into the cookie and how to populate the form.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the ASP.NET Profile system.

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111657/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/101106-1.aspx

Comment: any suggestion on how to do this using jQuery or Javascript on the client side?

Comment: I don't think priceline is setting cookies directly fromm javascript. I think they would make an ajax call to the server side to store your settings. If so then you need to create a webservice or pagemethod that you can call from client side to save the settinsgs. The webserivce or pagemethod will store the values in the profile system.